# Informal way of saying 'to be on the list'

Tags: colloquialisms

> Did you check out your ingore list? If I **am on the list**, cross my name off there.

Are there any informal phrases in English that mean the same as in the example above? As I mean the ignore list as part of a user account on the website, the verb *cross off* is used figuratively here, and is supposed to be synonymous with 'remove from'. I hope to find colloquialisms that convey the said sense.

Thanks.

Comment: Such "lists" are invariably held in computer databases these days, so it makes more sense to ask for your phone number, address, or whatever to be *deleted*, not *crossed off*.

Comment: I think I've heard people say "un-block me", in this sense. (But ask around to confirm it.)

Comment: "Did you check your ignore list? Make sure I'm not on it."

Comment: @FumbleFingers By being in the ignore list, I mean the situation when a user has been mistakenly included in the ignore list provided by a communication resource (for example, the ignore list on Facebook), and now this user is invisible for those who bloked the user by mistake. So the user can't message them again or the others can't see his/her comments...something like that.

Comment: @Oldbag 'un-block me' seems suitable for me!

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, I think I would say 'If I am on the list, take me off'.  'Cross me off' is also common.  There is no need to say 'my name'.